# AppleScript: Select a substring of currently selected text

Tags: applescript

Say if I selected some text in an app like Notes.

I can get the text delimited by a colon by the following code with Automator.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set lineSubject to text 1 thru ((offset of ":" in input)-1) of item 1 of input
    Display Dialog lineSubject
    return input
end run
```

However, what if, after finding the substring, I want to modify the current selection range so that this substring I got is now selected by the application instead, or what if I even change the font of the substring, e.g., making it bold?

Comment: I do not believe this is possible in _Notes_ because, looking through its AppleScript dictionary, there is no `selection` property, and no Text Suite, allowing one to manipulate fonts, etc.

Comment: @CJK ok... too bad but thanks!